# Apply a routed event handler to an application bar button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to assign a routed event handler to a method that contains routed event arguments. I am constantly receiving this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

Here is the function:

```
private void lists_AddListButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("list.xml"))
            {
                XDocument document = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), new XElement("lists", new XElement("list", new XElement("name", "random list"), new XElement("date", DateTime.Now.ToString()))));
                document.Save(stream);

                var items = (from query in document.Descendants("list")
                            select new ListsXmlBinder
                            {
                                Name = query.Element("name").Value,
                                Date = query.Element("date").Value
                            }).ToList();

                lists_ListViewer.ItemsSource =  items;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is where I am trying to assign the event handler:

```
private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
       // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
        appBarButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(lists_AddListButton_Click);
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
    }
```

The event handler is where the new `RoutedEventHandler` part is. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, ApplicationBarIconButton.Click is EventHandler, not RoutedEventHandler. So try to change

```
appBarButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(lists_AddListButton_Click);
```

to

```
appBarButton.Click += new EventHandler(lists_AddListButton_Click);
```

or just

```
appBarButton.Click += lists_AddListButton_Click;
```

as Jogy recommends

and

```
void lists_AddListButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

to

```
void lists_AddListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the response. I will keep that in mind. ;)

Comment: @user5662596 , If it solved your problem, you suppose to accept the answer, either mine, either Jogy's, which is pretty much the same, to keep people motivated to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why you would need a RoutedEventHandler.
Change the RoutedEventArgs parameter of lists_AddListButton_Click to simply EventArgs - you do not even use it in the method.
Then you can change the code to appBarButton.Click += lists_AddListButton_Click;